# Spring Integration with AMQP: get original message's custom-headers on error-channel

Tags: error-handling, spring-integration, spring-amqp

Using Spring Integration with RabbitMQ in my project I face a problem.
The project consist of receiving messaging from a queue, trace the incoming message, process the message using a service-activator, and trace the response or the exception thrown by the service activator.
Here is the sample configuration:

```
<!-- inbound-gateway -->
<int-amqp:inbound-gateway id="inboundGateway"
         request-channel="gatewayRequestChannel"
         queue-names="myQueue"
         connection-factory="rabbitMQConnectionFactory"
         reply-channel="gatewayResponseChannel"
         error-channel="gatewayErrorChannel"
         error-handler="rabbitMQErrorHandler"
         mapped-request-headers="traceId"
         mapped-reply-headers="traceId" />

<!-- section to dispatch incoming messages to trace and execute service-activator -->
<int:publish-subscribe-channel id="gatewayRequestChannel" />
<int:bridge input-channel="gatewayRequestChannel" output-channel="traceChannel"/>
<int:bridge input-channel="gatewayRequestChannel" output-channel="serviceActivatorInputChannel"/>

<!-- the trace channel-->
<int:logging-channel-adapter id="traceChannel" 
    expression="headers['traceId'] + '= [Headers=' + headers + ', Payload=' + payload+']'" logger-name="my.logger" level="DEBUG" />

<!-- service activator which may throw an exception -->
<int:service-activator ref="myBean" method="myMethod" input-channel="serviceActivatorInputChannel" output-channel="serviceActivatorOutputChannel"/>

<!-- section to dispatch output-messages from service-activator to trace them and return them to the gateway -->
<int:publish-subscribe-channel id="serviceActivatorOutputChannel" />
<int:bridge input-channel="serviceActivatorOutputChannel"
    output-channel="traceChannel" />
<int:bridge input-channel="serviceActivatorOutputChannel"
    output-channel="gatewayResponseChannel" />

<!-- section to dispatch exceptions from service-activator to trace them and return them to the gateway -->
<int:bridge input-channel="gatewayErrorChannel"
    output-channel="traceChannel" />
<int:bridge input-channel="gatewayErrorChannel"
    output-channel="gatewayResponseChannel" />
```

I simplified the code to suit my explanation. The idea is to trace the input and output/error messages coming and outgoing to/from the service-activator. To do this, I use a message's header named *traceId*. This identifier is used as a correlation-identifier to be able to associate the request-message with its response (these two messages share the same *traceId* value).

Everything is working fine when no exception is thrown by the service-activator.
But when an exception is thrown, it seems a new message is generated by the gateway, without my original *traceId* header.

Looking a little bit into the gateway code, I find the following piece of code into the class *org.springframework.integration.gateway.MessagingGatewaySupport* :

```
private Object doSendAndReceive(Object object, boolean shouldConvert) {
...
    if (error != null) {
                if (this.errorChannel != null) {
                    Message<?> errorMessage = new ErrorMessage(error);
                    Message<?> errorFlowReply = null;
                    try {
                        errorFlowReply = this.messagingTemplate.sendAndReceive(this.errorChannel, errorMessage);
                    }
...
}
```

It seems that, when an exception occurred, a new message is created with the exception message as payload and is sent to the gateway's errorChannel. Here is where I loose my custom headers.

Is there a way to preserve my custom-headers when an exception is occurring? (maybe there is a way to configure it and I may be missing it...). Or maybe I am not implementing my flow in a right way. If this is the case, any comment or suggestion is welcome.

By the way, I am using the version 4.0.3.RELEASE of the spring-integration-core artifact.

Thanks for yours answers

Edit: as Gary Russel said, this exemple is missing the following puslish/subscribe queue configuration

```
<int:publish-subscribe-channel id="gatewayErrorChannel"/>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The message on the `error-channel` is an `ErrorMessage`. It has two properties: `cause` - the original exception and `failedMessage` - the message at the point of failure. The `ErrorMessage` does not get the `failedMessage`'s headers.

You can't just send the `ErrorMessage` back to the gateway without some extra work.

Typically, error flows will perform some analysis of the error before returning a response.

If you want to restore some custom header, you will need a header enricher on the error flow.

Something like

```
<int:header-enricher ...>
    <int:header name="traceId" expression="payload.failedMessage.headers.traceId" />
</int:header-enricher>
```

In addition, your configuration is a little odd in that you have 2 subscribers on `gatewayErrorChannel`. Unless it is a `<publish-subscribe-channel/>`, these consumers will get alternate messages; it seems like you expect them both to get it so you need to declare the channel properly.

Comment: It works perfectly! It was just in front of my eyes, I was looking too deeply. Thanks a lot!